# IndexError: too many indices for array y.append(line[17])

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, index-error

I'm suppose to be writing code to read the x, y, and z positions of galaxies using the minnimillenium and I keep getting this error message:

```
y.append(line[17])

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I know basically nothing about coding and I was wondering if someone could help me by explaining what this means and maybe how to fix it.

```
import numpy as np
#x=[]
y=[]
#z=[]

filename=(r"C:\Users\Melis\OneDrive\Documents\minnimill3.txt")
f1=open(filename)
while 1:
    rawline = f1.readline()
    lines = rawline.strip()
    if lines == '':
        break
    if lines[0] != '#' and lines[0] != 'x':
        line = np.array(map(float, lines.split(',')))
        print (line)
    y.append(line[17])
   # z.append(line[18])

f1.close()
```

This is what the file is

```
#COLUMN 1 name=galaxyID JDBC_TYPE=-5 JDBC_TYPENAME=bigint
#COLUMN 2 name=lastProgenitorId JDBC_TYPE=-5 JDBC_TYPENAME=bigint
#COLUMN 3 name=descendantId JDBC_TYPE=-5 JDBC_TYPENAME=bigint
#COLUMN 4 name=haloID JDBC_TYPE=-5 JDBC_TYPENAME=bigint
#COLUMN 5 name=subHaloID JDBC_TYPE=-5 JDBC_TYPENAME=bigint
#COLUMN 6 name=fofID JDBC_TYPE=-5 JDBC_TYPENAME=bigint
#COLUMN 7 name=treeId JDBC_TYPE=-5 JDBC_TYPENAME=bigint
#COLUMN 8 name=firstProgenitorId JDBC_TYPE=-5 JDBC_TYPENAME=bigint
#COLUMN 9 name=nextProgenitorId JDBC_TYPE=-5 JDBC_TYPENAME=bigint
#COLUMN 10 name=type JDBC_TYPE=4 JDBC_TYPENAME=int
#COLUMN 11 name=snapnum JDBC_TYPE=4 JDBC_TYPENAME=int
#COLUMN 12 name=redshift JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 13 name=centralMvir JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 14 name=phkey JDBC_TYPE=4 JDBC_TYPENAME=int
#COLUMN 15 name=x JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 16 name=y JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 17 name=z JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 18 name=zIndex JDBC_TYPE=-5 JDBC_TYPENAME=bigint
#COLUMN 19 name=ix JDBC_TYPE=4 JDBC_TYPENAME=int 
#COLUMN 20 name=iy JDBC_TYPE=4 JDBC_TYPENAME=int
#COLUMN 21 name=iz JDBC_TYPE=4 JDBC_TYPENAME=int
#COLUMN 22 name=velX JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 23 name=velY JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 24 name=velZ JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 25 name=np JDBC_TYPE=4 JDBC_TYPENAME=int 
#COLUMN 26 name=mvir JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 27 name=rvir JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 28 name=vvir JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 29 name=vmax JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 30 name=coldGas JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 31 name=stellarMass JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 32 name=bulgeMass JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 33 name=hotGas JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 34 name=ejectedMass JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 35 name=blackHoleMass JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 36 name=metalsColdGas JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 37 name=metalsStellarMass JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 38 name=metalsBulgeMass JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 39 name=metalsHotGas JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 40 name=metalsEjectedMass JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 41 name=sfr JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 42 name=sfrBulge JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 43 name=xrayLum JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 44 name=diskRadius JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 45 name=coolingRadius JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 46 name=mag_b JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 47 name=mag_v JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 48 name=mag_r JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 49 name=mag_i JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 50 name=mag_k JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 51 name=mag_bBulge JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 52 name=mag_vBulge JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 53 name=mag_rBulge JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 54 name=mag_iBulge JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 55 name=mag_kBulge JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 56 name=mag_bDust JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 57 name=mag_vDust JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 58 name=mag_rDust JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 59 name=mag_iDust JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 60 name=mag_kDust JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 61 name=massWeightedAge JDBC_TYPE=7 JDBC_TYPENAME=real
#COLUMN 62 name=random JDBC_TYPE=4 JDBC_TYPENAME=int
galaxyID,lastProgenitorId,descendantId,haloID,subHaloID,fofID,treeId,firstProgenitorId,nextProgenitorId,type,snapnum,redshift,centralMvir,phkey,x,y,z,zIndex,ix,iy,iz,velX,velY,velZ,np,mvir,rvir,vvir,vmax,coldGas,stellarMass,bulgeMass,hotGas,ejectedMass,blackHoleMass,metalsColdGas,metalsStellarMass,metalsBulgeMass,metalsHotGas,metalsEjectedMass,sfr,sfrBulge,xrayLum,diskRadius,coolingRadius,mag_b,mag_v,mag_r,mag_i,mag_k,mag_bBulge,mag_vBulge,mag_rBulge,mag_iBulge,mag_kBulge,mag_bDust,mag_vDust,mag_rDust,mag_iDust,mag_kDust,massWeightedAge,random
```

Then there are a bunch of comma separated numbers and letters.

Comment: Can you show what your file looks like?  `too many indices for array` usually refers to there being a shape conflict with an array.

Comment: If your data is just a csv, try changing: `line = np.array(map(float, lines.split(',')))` to `line = np.array(list(map(float, lines.split(','))))` that fixed the error for me.

Comment: So obviously not every line has at least 18 values...

Comment: @ascripter I don't think that's the issue, I believe giving `np.array()` an iterator instead of a sequence is the problem.  The error you describe would throw: `index 17 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size`